# When Can a Use Unqualified Tablenames in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

The Google BigQuery Query Reference for Standard SQL contains the
following examples of table_name specification:

The name (optionally qualified) of an existing table.
SELECT * FROM Roster;
SELECT * FROM dataset.Roster;
SELECT * FROM project.dataset.Roster;

In-house, whenever we try to use an unqualified table name we get
an error from GBQ: "Table name cannot be resolved: dataset name
is missing".
When can an unqualified name be used (as in the first example
above)??? 
Let me know.
Efrem

Answer (score 0):

You can use just table as in Below example ONLY when it belong to [default Dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.defaultDataset)

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
```

Default Dataset is used to specify the default dataset to use by BigQuery Engine for unqualified table names in the query and can be set in respective API (see link above).

To avoid setting for each and every query in API - you can specify a default dataset for your environment. See [How to Set a default dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#defaultdataset)